# tcpdf auto size text field

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am having trouble getting a text field to auto size on a form I'm creating. I am setting the textSize of the properties to 0 in the properties of the TextField but it seems to just use the font set for the document. Here is the code I am using to create the TextField.

```
$pdf->TextField('description', 195, 32, array('multiline'=>true, 'lineWidth'=>0, 'borderStyle'=>'none', 'textSize'=>0), array('v'=>$description));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a kinda round-about way of possibly fixing this..

Before your textfield code, what ever you would like your font to be (not the default for the entire document) you could always try:

```
$pdf->SetFont('fontName','',fontSize);
```

And after your textfield code, just set the font back to what ever you wanted it to be for the rest of the document.

Not really sure if this was exactly what you were looking for, but I hope it helps. Good luck with it all.

Answer (score 0):

I faced also that exact problem. I had a long time before I could find out the solution to this.

To make the field auto size the textual content, the font size of the field must be set to 0. It looks like TCPDF doesn’t support the javascript `textSize` option (see at the end of [`TCPDF_STATIC::getAnnotOptFromJSProp()`](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/64fc19439863e1b1314487a72a74d9bfd0b55a53/include/tcpdf_static.php#L1003) ), so we must set the font size to 0 before the field, and set back again to its original value after the text field :

```
// Beware to use getFontSize*Pt* and not getFontSize.
// getFontSizePt gets the size in pt, and getFontSize gets the size in user units
// (units you gave when you created TCPDF object or default to mm)
// We need to set it again back with SetFontSize() which takes the font size in pt
$originalFontSize = $pdf->getFontSizePt();
$pdf->SetFontSize(0);
$pdf->TextField($name, $w, $h);
$pdf->SetFontSize($originalFontSize);
```